# Is it possible to execute query to mirror database? (MS SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql-server-2012, mirroring

Is it possible to execute query to mirror database? Without stopping mirroring.

Answer (score 0):

In database mirroring you can query the mirrored database only if you create snapshots of that database. In SQL Server 2012, database snapshot is an Enterprise feature.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/cc645993(v%3dsql.110)

If you run queries on the snapshot you'll lave to license it, and are a few things to consider, check link below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/database-mirroring/database-mirroring-and-database-snapshots-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

If you're willing to license Enterprise, you'd be better of implementing AlywasOn Availability Groups where you can have a readable secondary.